# Python Pandas: Eliminate a row from a dataframe if a value in a any preceding row in a groupby meets a certain criteria

Tags: python, pandas, row, slice

I am trying to remove data from a groupby once the Week becomes non-sequential by more than 1. i.e. If there is a gap in a week then i want to remove that row and subsequent rows in that group by. below is a simple example of the sort of structure of data I have and also the ideal output I am looking for. The data needs to be grouped by Country and Product.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Country' : ['US','US','US','US','US','DE','DE','DE','DE','DE'],'Product' :         ['Coke','Coke','Coke','Coke','Coke','Apple','Apple','Apple','Apple','Apple'],'Week' : [1,2,3,4,6,1,2,3,5,6] }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print df

#Current starting Dataframe.
  Country Product  Week
0      US    Coke     1
1      US    Coke     2
2      US    Coke     3
3      US    Coke     4
4      US    Coke     6
5      DE   Apple     1
6      DE   Apple     2
7      DE   Apple     3
8      DE   Apple     5
9      DE   Apple     6

#Ideal Output below:
  Country Product  Week
0      US    Coke     1
1      US    Coke     2
2      US    Coke     3
3      US    Coke     4
5      DE   Apple     1
6      DE   Apple     2
7      DE   Apple     3
```

So the output removes Week 6 for the US Coke because the preceding week was 4.
For DE Apple Week 5 & 6 was removed because the preceding Week to Week 5 was 3. note this also eliminates DE Apple Week 6 even though its preceding is 5 or a diff() of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
df.groupby(['Country', 'Product']).apply(lambda sdf: sdf[(sdf.Week.diff(1).fillna(1) != 1).astype('int').cumsum() == 0]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Another method, that might be more readable (i.e. generate a set of consecutive weeks and check against the observed week)

```
df['expected_week'] = df.groupby(['Country', 'Product']).Week.transform(lambda s: range(s.min(), s.min() + s.size))
df[df.Week == df.expected_week]
```

Comment: thanks, it worked for dropping the US Coke 6, and DE Apple 5. But DE Apple 6 remains.

Comment: Thanks the first one works now, but it produced the opposite if I change the .cumsum() == 1 to .cumsum() != 1]) it is perfect. The second one I like the logic its easier for me to understand adding an additional column, but i was getting some strange error message."TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index" thanks for all your input.

Answer (score 1):

You could try out this method...

```
def eliminate(x):
    x['g'] = x['Week'] - np.arange(x.shape[0])
    x = x[x['g'] == x['g'].min()]
    x = x.drop('g',1)

    return x

out  = df.groupby('Product').apply(eliminate).reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
```

Comment: Thanks @ZJS, this gives me a good view of using a function instead of a lambda, lamdas still confuse the heck out of me. When i ran your code it looked good except it also seemed to Drop US Coke Week 4 which I need to maintain as it is still in sequence to the preceding week.